# I get this error "Unhandled exception at 0x009437bd in Hash functions.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I get this error over and over again when I run my project. Don't know where is the problem. I know it's about some free memory I used again, or a null pointer or access to a non exist memory but actually I checked all the pointers and they are declared as what they should to be.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

typedef struct ND {
  int ID;
  char* Name;
  char* Address;
  int Age;
  double GPA;
  ND * next;
} NODE;

class HF {
private :
  int count;
  int size ;
  int prime;
  int a ,b;
  NODE ** HT;
public: 
  HF ();
  HF ( int n , int p , int a, int b);
  ~ HF ();
  int findindex(int key);
  bool insert (int ID,char* Name,char* Address,int Age,double GPA);
  bool retrieve (int & ID,char* & Name,char* & Address,int & Age,double & GPA);
  bool remove(int key);
  double GetLoadFactor ();
};

HF :: HF ()
{
  size = 100;
  prime = 997;
  a = 23 ;
  b = 88;
  count =0;
  HT = new NODE* [size];
  for (int i=0; i< size ; i++)
      HT[i] = NULL;
  }

HF :: HF ( int n , int p , int a, int b)
{
  size = n;
  prime = p;
  a = a;
  b = b;
  count = 0;
  HT = new NODE* [size];
  for (int i=0; i< size ; i++)
      HT[i] = NULL;
}

HF :: ~ HF ()
{
  NODE *p;
  for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
  {
      while (HT[i] != NULL)
      {
          p = HT[i];
          HT[i] = HT[i] -> next ;
              delete p;
      }
  }
  delete  [] HT ;
}

int HF :: findindex(int key)
{
  int index ;
  index = (((a*(key)+b) % prime) % size) ;
  index = index % size ;
  return index;
}

bool HF :: insert (int ID,char* Name,char* Address,int Age,double GPA)
{
  int i ;
  NODE * n;
  n = new NODE;
  n -> ID = ID;
  n -> Address = Address;
  n -> Name = Name;
  n -> Age = Age;
  n -> GPA = GPA;
  n -> next = NULL;
  i = findindex(ID);
  if ( HT[i] == NULL)
  {
      HT[i] = n;
  }
  else
  {
      n -> next = HT[i];
      HT[i] = n;
  }
  count ++ ;
  return true;
}

  bool HF ::retrieve (int & key,char* & Name,char * &Address,int & Age,double & GPA)
  {
  int i ;
  NODE *p;
  i = findindex(key);
  if ( HT[i] == NULL)
  {
      return false;
  }
  else
  {
      p = HT[i];
      if ( HT[i] -> ID == key)// here is the break point
      { 
          key = p-> ID ;
          Name = p-> Name ;
          Address = p-> Address ;
          Age = p-> Age;
          GPA = p-> GPA ;
          return true ; 
       }
       while ( p != NULL)
       {
          if ( p-> ID == key)
          { 
              key = p-> ID ;
              Name = p-> Name ;
              Address = p-> Address ;
              Age = p-> Age;
              GPA = p-> GPA ;
              return true ; 
          }
          else
              p = p-> next ;
          }
    }
    return false;
  }
bool HF :: remove (int key)
 {

int i ;
NODE *p1 , *p2;
i = findindex(key);
if ( HT[i] == NULL)
{
    return false;
}

else
{
    p1 =p2 = HT[i];
    if(HT[i] -> ID == key)
    {
        HT[i] = HT[i] -> next;
        delete p2;
        return true;
    }


    while ( p2 != NULL)
    {
        if ( p2 -> ID == key)
        { 
            p1 -> next = p2 -> next ;
            delete p2;

            count --;
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {

            p1 =p2;
            p2 = p2 -> next;

        }
    }


}
return false;

 }

 double HF :: GetLoadFactor()
 {
double L;

L = (double) count/size ;
return L;
}

int main ()
{
double L;
int x,age;
char * name , *address;
double GPA;
HF UHashFunc1;
HF UHashFunc2( 11 , 7 , 3 , 0);

 UHashFunc1.insert( 6 , "Ahmed" , "Jenin" , 20 , 3.5);
 UHashFunc1.insert( 1 , "Sarah" , "Jenin" , 18 , 3.2);
 UHashFunc1.insert(40 , "Mohammad" , "Tolkrem", 19 , 3.0);
 UHashFunc1.insert(2 , "Ala'a" , "Jerusalem", 19 , 2.6);
 UHashFunc1.insert(41 , "Raghad" , "Tolkrem", 19 , 1.6);
 UHashFunc1.insert(80 , "Mohammad" , "Jenin", 22 , 2.7);
 UHashFunc1.insert(83 , "Murad" , "Nablus", 18 , 3.7);
 UHashFunc1.insert(44 , "Reem" , "Hebron", 19 , 2.9);
 UHashFunc1.insert(50 , "Wajde" , "Qalqelya", 20, 1.7);
 UHashFunc1.insert(42 , "Belal" , "Hebron", 20 , 3.4);
 UHashFunc1.insert(3 , "Ahmed" , "Nablus", 21 , 1.9);
 UHashFunc1.insert(84 , "Haitham" , "Nablus", 21 , 3.1);


cout <<"enter the ID you want to retrieve"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc1.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA))
{
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
}
else
    cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;

cout <<"enter the ID you want to retrieve"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc1.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA))
{
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
}
else
    cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
cout << "The current load factor is : " << L <<endl;
UHashFunc1.remove(42);
L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
cout << "The current load factor is : " << L <<endl;
x=84;
UHashFunc1.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
x=1;
UHashFunc1.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
x=50;
UHashFunc1.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;

cout << "Enter The ID you want to remove"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc1.remove(x))
    {
    L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing a record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}

if(UHashFunc1.remove(2))
    {
    L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing a record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}
 UHashFunc1.insert( 45 , "Amjad" , "Nablus" , 19 , 2.0);
 L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
 cout << "The current load factor after adding a record is : " << L <<endl;
 if(UHashFunc1.remove(80))
    {
    L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing the record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}
 if(UHashFunc1.remove(50))
    {
    L=UHashFunc1.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing the record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}

  UHashFunc2.insert( 5 , "Ahmed" , "Jenin" , 20 , 3.5);
 UHashFunc2.insert( 1 , "Sarah" , "Jenin" , 18 , 3.2);
 UHashFunc2.insert(9 , "Mohammad" , "Tolkrem", 19 , 3.0);
 UHashFunc2.insert(2 , "Ala'a" , "Jerusalem", 19 , 2.6);
 UHashFunc2.insert(8 , "Raghad" , "Tolkrem", 19 , 1.6);
 UHashFunc2.insert(100 , "Mohammad" , "Jenin", 22 , 2.7);
 UHashFunc2.insert(50 , "Murad" , "Nablus", 18 , 3.7);
 UHashFunc2.insert(23 , "Reem" , "Hebron", 19 , 2.9);
 UHashFunc2.insert(40 , "Wajde" , "Qalqelya", 20, 1.7);
 UHashFunc2.insert(17 , "Belal" , "Hebron", 20 , 3.4);
 UHashFunc2.insert(3 , "Ahmed" , "Nablus", 21 , 1.9);
 UHashFunc2.insert(7 , "Haitham" , "Nablus", 21 , 3.1);

 cout <<"enter the ID you want to retrieve from the 2nd Func"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc2.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA))
{
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
}
else
    cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;

cout <<"enter the ID you want to retrieve from the 2nd Func"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc2.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA))
{
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
}
else
    cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;

L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
cout << "The current load factor is : " << L <<endl;
UHashFunc2.remove(2);
L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
cout << "The current load factor is : " << L <<endl;
x=5;
UHashFunc2.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
x=1;
UHashFunc2.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;
x=50;
UHashFunc2.retrieve(x,name,address,age,GPA);
cout << "ID:"<<x<<endl;
cout << "Name:"<<name<<endl;
cout << "Address:"<<address<<endl;
cout << "Age:"<<age<<endl;
cout << "GPA:"<<GPA<<endl;

cout << "Enter The ID you want to remove from the 2nd Func"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if(UHashFunc2.remove(x))
    {
    L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing a record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}

if(UHashFunc2.remove(2))
    {
    L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing a record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}
 UHashFunc2.insert( 45 , "Amjad" , "Nablus" , 19 , 2.0);
 L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
 cout << "The current load factor after adding a record is : " << L <<endl;
 if(UHashFunc2.remove(100))
    {
    L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing the record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}
 if(UHashFunc2.remove(9))
    {
    L=UHashFunc2.GetLoadFactor();
     cout << "The current load factor after removing the record is : " << L <<endl;
}
else 
{ cout << "NOT Exist"<<endl;}


cin>>x;



return 0;
 }
```

There are no building errors just these ones when break point

> First-chance exception at 0x009437bd in Hash functions.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x009437bd in Hash functions.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000001. First-chance exception at
>   0x009437bd in Hash functions.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x00000001. The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1e40) has exited
>   with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a). The program '[788] Hash
>   functions.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Comment: You need to learn how to enable all warnings for your compiler, how to get your compiler produce debug information inside a debuggable executable, and how to use the debugger.

Comment: Isnt Access Violation thrown when you try to access something that points to NULL?

Comment: @mslot - or when you read/write something that's not mapped

Comment: it should be,,, but there is no NULL pointer !!!!

Comment: Guys guys guys.... This fellow is expecting help. Look he is new to here, and probably to software development as well. Don't be rude and criticize him and make fun of him. English may not be his first language either....

Comment: yeah it isn't ,,!! thnx alot anyway 
its my first year student as computer engineer and I really need some help
thnx

Comment: @Beesan Oh, so this is a homework? If it is, could you add the restrictions so we can give you better tips to help you improve your code?

Comment: Check out my answer Beesan, I have the solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to easily reproduce the error you ran into.
You have a constructor for HF that takes parameters like this:

```
HF :: HF ( int n , int p , int a, int b)
{
    size = n;
    prime = p;
    a = a;
    b = b;
```

As you can see the parameter names a and b are exactly the same as the member variable names. Hence HF::a and HF::b are never assigned values. Hence they are always uninitialized and contain garbage. Hence you get nothing but random values, and all the hashing stuff you are trying to do doesn't work as a result.

You should change the parameter names to something different. Say with capital letters perhaps:

```
HF :: HF ( int n , int p , int A, int B)
{
    size = n;
    prime = p;
    a = A;
    b = B;
```

Once I do that, it solves all the memory corruption errors, and it runs to completion just fine.

Comment: One tip I could also give as a result of this, is to always name member variables with a name that is unique. For instance it is a standard practice to name member variables with a prefix like 'm' or 'm_'. Hence you could name the member variables for HF like 'mCount', 'mA' and 'mB'. That would have solved all your head-aches very early.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use, and then apply, `std::vector<T>`, `std::string`, `std::shared_ptr<T>`, `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Then come back if problem persists.

Comment: @Beesan: I prefer effectiveness.

Comment: I know @DeadMG's comment might seems rude, but he is kind of right. using `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` will not only simplify and make your code more robust, but it will also be usefull for your entire life as a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a NULL pointer. You are accessing memory location 1 (0x00000001), which is 1 byte offset from NULL (aka 0x00000000). The code you posted is verbose and a bit of a mess, and without a line number where you are accessing the pointer, it's hard to say where exactly you are accessing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Also sounds like a NULL pointer, though not sure how given the `while(p2 != NULL)`. You should look at these pointer values in a debugger.